# How to call and return the array data in other method

Tags: objective-c, arrays, nsmutablearray

I have the below method and I want to call it and return the array data in another method but that does not work. but the self in the other method returns no data?

```
- (NSMutableArray *)glo
{
    NSMutableArray *globalarray = [[NSMutableArray array]init];
    for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
        [globalarray addObject: [NSNumber numberWithInt: arc4random()%200]];
        return globalarray ;
    }
}


-(IBAction)clicked_insertsort:(id)sender{
    [self glo];
}
```

Comment: i need to return the array data in the clikked_insert method but the console shows no data however i checked the code alone for the random and it worked fine

Comment: @H2CO3, see the code... I guess, in that sense. **1.** to return a value from inside a loop? **2.** the caller does not take care of the return value. I would not understand if it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I really try to replace some part in your code to something like this:

```
- (NSMutableArray *)glo
{
    NSMutableArray *globalarray = [[NSMutableArray array] init];
    for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
        [globalarray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt: arc4random()%200]];
    }
    return globalarray; // pull out from the loop
}
```

and this:

```
-(IBAction)clicked_insertsort:(id)sender{
    NSMutableArray *array = [self glo]; // take care of the return value
    NSLog(@"array : %@", array)
}
```

---

**UPDATE:**

if you want a global variable in you class you should define the following:

```
@interface YourClass : NSObject {
    NSMutableArray *globalarray;
}

// ...

@end
```

and the methods will be the following (no return value needed, because the variable is available from the whole class now)

```
- (void)glo {
    if (!globalarray) {
        globalarray = [NSMutableArray array];
        for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
            [globalarray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt: arc4random()%200]];
        }
    }            
}
```

Comment: @OracleOracle, what static array? in your code fragment there is no static array... you have just a local array in your `-glo` method.